# how to copy the dependencies libraries JARs in gradle

Tags: copy, dependencies, gradle

I got a runnable jar with this `build.gradle`

```java
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    manifest.mainAttributes("Main-Class" : "com.test.HelloWorld")

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile (
            'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6',
            'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1',
            'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.6',
            'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.6',
            'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0',
            'junit:junit:4.+'
        )
    }
```

but it run failed, because the dependencies jars can't find.

and then I add this code:

```java
    task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
        into "$buildDir/output/libs"
        from configurations.runtime
    }
```

but nothing change. I can't find the folder output/libs.

how can I copy the dependencies libs jars to a specified folder or path?

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Niederwieserfirst i run: gradle build, get the runnable jar file 
then ,run the jar file: java -jar XXX.jar

Comment: You probably want to use Sync instead of Copy. See also https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:sync_task

Answer (score 47):

Add:

```
build.dependsOn(copyToLib)
```

When `gradle build` runs, Gradle builds tasks and whatever tasks depend on it (declared by `dependsOn`). Without setting `build.dependsOn(copyToLib)`, Gradle will not associate the copy task with the build task.

So:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

manifest.mainAttributes('Main-Class': 'com.test.HelloWorld')

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile (
        'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6',
        'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1',
        'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1',
        'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1',
        'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1',
        'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1',
        'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.6',
        'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.6',
        'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0',
        'junit:junit:4.+'
    )
}

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "${buildDir}/output/libs"
    from configurations.runtime
}

build.dependsOn(copyToLib)
```

Comment: In SonarQube analysis, during Javacode AST scan, I was getting ERROR/WARN - Class xx.yy.zz not found. To fix that, I had to set "sonar.java.libraries" which contains all the jar (dependencies) required during compile, testCompile, runtime. I added "from configurations.compile from configurations.testCompile from configurations.runtime". I got all the jars in "build/dependent-jars" folder. Setting sonar.java.libraries=build/dependent-jars/*.jar I'm not getting error. Thanks, as gradle maintains its cache outside of workspace but using this code I was able to get the .jar in build folder.

Answer (score 18):

I find the application plugin way too cumbersome and too verbose in its output. Here's how I finally got a setup I was happy with, i.e., create a distribution zip file with dependency jars in subdirectory `/lib` and add all dependencies to `Class-Path` entry in the manifest file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
}

// Task "distZip" added by plugin "java-library-distribution":
distZip.shouldRunAfter(build)

jar {
    // Keep jar clean:
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.somepackage.MainClass',
                   'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }
    // How-to add class path:
    //     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659463/add-classpath-in-manifest-using-gradle
    //     https://gist.github.com/simon04/6865179
}
```

Hosted as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/c63675ce87947da1ef4a).

The result can be found in `build/distributions` and the unzipped contents look like this:

> lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar 
>   MyJarFile.jar

Contents of `MyJarFile.jar#META-INF/MANIFEST.mf`:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 
>   Main-Class: com.somepackage.MainClass 
>   Class-Path: lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar

Answer (score 8):

Since Gradle 6.0 it is:

```kotlin
tasks {
    val deps by registering(Copy::class) {
        from(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
        into("build/deps")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with all the previous answers is that they only collect dependencies from one configuration. To get ALL of the dependencies, you should use this:

```
task saveDependencies(type: Copy){
    configurations.each {
        if (it.isCanBeResolved())
            from it into "gradle_dependencies"
    }
    from buildscript.configurations.classpath into "gradle_dependencies"
}
```

Comment: when would you want to include compile time dependencies in a jar though?

Comment: @BradMace I dont include the dependencies into a jar. I simply copy them to a separate folder. You would want to do this when, for example, you have a bunch of remote dependencies and you are afraid of some repositories going offline, so you make a local copy of everything.

Answer (score 1):

The application plugin requires you to set the main class name like this:

```
mainClassName = "com.test.HelloWorld"
```

You will need to add that to your build script. Keep in mind that if you try to run your application with the `java` command you will also need to set the classpath with `-cp`.

The application plugin simplifies this process by providing the task [distZip](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N13F72). If you run that task you a full distribution is created for you under `build/distributions`. The distribution contains start scripts and all dependencies. The generated start scripts already set the classpath for you so you don't have to deal with it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The `java` plugin can pack a jar with dependencies and there's no need for the `application` plugin. A task like the following would do:

```
task buildWithDeps(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.test.HelloWorld"
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Comment: This will create a fat jar and the question is more about copying all the dependencies to a dir.

Answer (score 1):

As of at least Gradle 5.6.4 you'll want to do something closer to this.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'my.group1:my-module1:0.0.1'
    implementation 'my.group2:my-module2:0.0.1'
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.filter { it.exists() }.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle 7.4 with Groovy:

```
configurations {
    externalLib.extendsFrom(implementation)
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy){
    from configurations.externalLib{
        into '<dest-dir-name>'

        exclude('<if any jars need to be excluded>')
    }
}
```