# Creating runnable JAR with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle, executable-jar

Until now I created runnable JAR files via the Eclipse "Export..." functionallity but now I switched to IntelliJ IDEA and Gradle for build automation.

Some articles here suggest the "application" plugin, but this does not entirely lead to the result I expected (just a JAR, no start scripts or anything like this).

How can I achieve the same result Eclipse does with the "Export..." dialog?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

An executable jar file is just a jar file containing a Main-Class entry in its manifest. So you just need to configure the [jar task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) in order to add this entry in its manifest:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.foo.bar.MainClass'
    }
}
```

You might also need to add classpath entries in the manifest, but that would be done the same way.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

---

If you already have defined an application context, you can re-use the definition rather than duplicate it:

```java
application {
  // Define the main class for the application.
  mainClass = 'com.foo.bar.MainClass'
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClass
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for; but: I declared already dependencies in the build.gradle, do I really have to add manually the class path or can I re-use my dependency declaration?

Comment: You should be able to loop through the libraries inside the 'runtime' configuration and to concatenate them to create the Class-Path attribute value.

Comment: What do you mean with 'inseid the "runtime" configuration'? Sorry for stupid questions, I am quite new to Gradle ...

Comment: The gradle java plugin defines 4 "configurations" corresponding to 4 different classpaths: compile (used to compile the Java files), testCompile (which is used to compile the test Java source files), runtime (which is used to execute the application) and testRuntime (which is used to execute the tests). See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#configurations

Comment: Ah, thanks - than I understood it correct and manage to build the JAR, now I am frickeling with creating the classpath ;-) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Adding manifest attribute also as adding `chmod +x` attribute to a file is completely not enough to make JAR executable and absolutely not the same as Eclipse command `Export to` does.

Comment: gradle-shadow-plugin is better as stated below by Jared Burrows, see the getting started guide here: https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/getting-started/#default-java-groovy-tasks

Comment: How would I use this with the Kotlin DSL? When I tried it, I got an error; something like "Expression 'jar' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found"

Answer (score 120):

Both JB Nizet and Jorge_B's answers are correct.

In its simplest form, creating an executable JAR with Gradle is just a matter of adding the appropriate entries to the [manifest](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sub:manifest).  However, it's much more common to have dependencies that need to be included on the classpath, making this approach tricky in practice.

The [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) provides an alternate approach; instead of creating an executable JAR, it provides:

- a `run` task to facilitate easily running the application directly from the build
- an `installDist` task that generates a directory structure including the built JAR, all of the JARs that it depends on, and a startup script that pulls it all together into a program you can run
- `distZip` and `distTar` tasks that create archives containing a complete application distribution (startup scripts and JARs)

A third approach is to create a so-called "fat JAR" which is an executable JAR that includes not only your component's code, but also all of its dependencies.  There are a few different plugins that use this approach.  I've included links to a few that I'm aware of; I'm sure there are more.

- [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)
- [one-jar](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar)
- [spring-boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)
- [capsule](https://github.com/danthegoodman/gradle-capsule-plugin)

Comment: Just tried shadow and one-jar. I'll stick to one-jar: it is simpler and easier to use. Cool! thanks

Comment: Unfortunately one-jar does not work with recent versions of Gradle. See, for example, https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar/issues/34

Comment: [Here](http://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar) is a one-liner solution to build one-jar by modifying the jar task. I've found this to be the most convenient. Note that you need to add `configurations.runtime` to bundle runtime dependencies in the single jar.

Comment: I found "application plugin" to be suitable and flexible enough for my need.
It allows also to pack everything to zip and include/exclude extra files in that zip.
Also, it's possible to add another launcher script with additional entry point using custom task.

Comment: How would I execute the `.tar` / `.zip` files generated?

Comment: The .tar/.zip files mentioned are not directly executable.  You extract them and run the script bundled within.

Answer (score 41):

Least effort solution for me was to make use of the [gradle-shadow-plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)

Besides applying the plugin all that needs to be done is:

Configure the jar task to put your Main class into manifest

```
jar {
  manifest {
   attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.my.app.Main'
  }
}
```

Run the gradle task

```
./gradlew shadowJar
```

Take the ***app-version-all.jar*** from *build/libs/*

And finally execute it via:

```
java -jar app-version-all.jar
```

Comment: Here's a [full `build.gradle` example](https://gist.github.com/TurekBot/4a3cd406cb52dfd8bfb8022b982f0f6c).

Comment: When I do this build I get BUILD SUCCESSFUL but when I try to run jar file with java -jar build/libs/core-all-1.0.jar I get following error: Error: Could not find or load main class scanners.exchange.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scanners.exchange.Main Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: @LukaLopusina The class you specified isn't in your JAR file. If you're using kotlin, you need to say `'com.my.app.MainKt'`. Without more info, I can't help you further.

Comment: Current plugin Shadow v5.+ is compatible with Gradle 5.0+ and Java 7+ only.

Answer (score 38):

As others have noted, in order for a jar file to be executable, the application's entry point must be set in the `Main-Class` attribute of the manifest file. If the dependency class files are not collocated, then they need to be set in the `Class-Path` entry of the manifest file.

I have tried all kinds of plugin combinations and what not for the simple task of creating an executable jar and somehow someway, include the dependencies. All plugins seem to be lacking one way or another, but finally I got it like I wanted. No mysterious scripts, not a million different mini files polluting the build directory, a pretty clean build script file, and above all: not a million foreign third party class files merged into my jar archive.

*The following is a copy-paste from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28825171/1268003) for your convenience..*

[How-to] create a distribution zip file with dependency jars in subdirectory `/lib` and add all dependencies to `Class-Path` entry in the manifest file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
}

// Task "distZip" added by plugin "java-library-distribution":
distZip.shouldRunAfter(build)

jar {
    // Keep jar clean:
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.somepackage.MainClass',
                   'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }
    // How-to add class path:
    //     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659463/add-classpath-in-manifest-using-gradle
    //     https://gist.github.com/simon04/6865179
}
```

Hosted as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/c63675ce87947da1ef4a).

The result can be found in `build/distributions` and the unzipped contents look like this:

> lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar 
>   MyJarFile.jar

Contents of `MyJarFile.jar#META-INF/MANIFEST.mf`:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 
>   Main-Class: com.somepackage.MainClass 
>   Class-Path: lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar

Comment: The current application jar will be in the 'lib' directory of the distribution too. You have to either move it by had to the top directory or change this line:  
'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }  
to this:  
'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }

Comment: @MarcNuri Are you sure?  I tried using this approach for my application, and the current application jar was **not** in the `lib` directory of the produced zip/tar file, but rather was in `lib`'s parent directory, as this answer suggests.  This solution seemed to work perfectly for me.

Comment: @thejonwithnoh I'm sorry, you're right. I didn't see the solution proposed to use the "java-library-distribution" plugin. In my case I'm simply using the "application" plugin which does the same job with the main difference that all of the jar files (**including** the application jar) are located in the "lib" directory. Thus changing `"lib/$it.name"` to `"$it.name"` will do the job.

Comment: `configurations.runtime.files.collect` seems to be replaced with `configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect` as of Gradle 7.x

Answer (score 17):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**).

#### Method 1 (no need for `application` or other plugins)

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    // OR another notation
    // manifest {
    //     attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    // }
}
```

If you use any external libraries, use below code. Copy library JARs in *libs* sub-directory of where you put your result JAR. Make sure your library JAR files do not contain space in their file name.

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    manifest.attributes["Class-Path"] = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .joinToString(separator = " ") { file ->
            "libs/${file.name}"
        }
}
```

Note that Java requires us to use relative URLs for the `Class-Path` attribute. So, we cannot use the absolute path of Gradle dependencies (which is also prone to being changed and not available on other systems). If you want to use absolute paths, maybe [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47961942/8583692) will work.

Create the JAR with the following command:

```bash
./gradlew jar
```

The result JAR will be created in *build/libs/* directory by default.

#### Method 2: Embedding libraries (if any) in the result JAR (fat or uber JAR)

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MyMainClass"
    val dependencies = configurations
        .runtimeClasspath
        .get()
        .map(::zipTree) // OR .map { zipTree(it) }
    from(dependencies)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Creating the JAR is exactly the same as the previous method.

#### Method 3: Using the [Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) (to create a fat or uber JAR)

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.0.0"
}
// Shadow task depends on Jar task, so these will be reflected for Shadow as well
tasks.jar {
    manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "org.example.MainKt"
}
```

Create the JAR with this command:

```bash
./gradlew shadowJar
```

See [Shadow documentations](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/#configuring-the-jar-manifest) for more information about configuring the plugin.

## Running the created JAR

```bash
java -jar my-artifact.jar
```

The above solutions were tested with:

- Java 17
- Gradle 7.1 (which uses Kotlin 1.4.31 for *.kts* build scripts)

See the official [Gradle documentation for creating uber (fat) JARs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example).

For more information about manifests, see [Oracle Java Documentation: Working with Manifest files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Note that your resource files will be included in the JAR file automatically (assuming they were placed in */src/main/resources/* directory or any custom directory set as resources root in the build file). To access a resource file in your application, use this code (note the `/` at the start of names):

- Kotlin

  ```kotlin
  val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // Alternative ways:
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResource("/vegetables.txt").readText()
  // val vegetables = MyClass::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  // val vegetables = object{}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt").reader().readText()
  ```
- Java

  ```java
  var stream = MyClass.class.getResource("/vegetables.txt").openStream();
  // OR var stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/vegetables.txt");
  var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
  var vegetables = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
  ```

Comment: Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71092054/8583692) to create a new task instead of modifying the existing *Jar* task.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the SpringBoot plugin:

```
plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
}
```

Create the jar

```
gradle assemble
```

And then run it

```
java -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

Note: your project does NOT need to be a SpringBoot project to use this plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the 'installApp' task?  Does it not create a full directory with a set of start scripts?

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: From what I understand, `installApp` doesn't create a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I do not see `installApp` task in the task list of [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks). Did you mean `installDist` instead?

Comment: Yes, `installApp` was renamed to `installDist` in Gradle 3.0. Here is the [release note](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/release-notes.html).

Answer (score 5):

Thank you Konstantin, it worked like a charm with few nuances. For some reason, specifying main class as part of jar manifest did not quite work and it wanted the mainClassName attribute instead. Here is a snippet from build.gradle that includes everything to make it work:

```
plugins {
  id 'java' 
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.2'
}
...
...
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
...
...
mainClassName = 'com.acme.myapp.MyClassMain'
...
...
...
shadowJar {
    baseName = 'myapp'
}
```

After running gradle shadowJar you get myapp-{version}-all.jar in your build folder which can be run as java -jar myapp-{version}-all.jar.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a jar artifact in the module settings (or project structure).

- Right click the module > Open module settings > Artifacts > + > JAR > from modules with dependencies.
- Set the main class.

Making a jar is then as easy as clicking "Build artifact..." from the Build menu. As a bonus, you can package all the dependencies into a single jar.

Tested on IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2):

I checked quite some links for the solution, finally did the below mentioned steps to get it working. I am using Gradle 2.9.

Make the following changes in your build,gradle file :

1. Mention plugin:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'eu.appsatori.fatjar'
   ```
2. Provide the Buildscript:

   ```
   buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath "eu.appsatori:gradle-fatjar-plugin:0.3"
   }
   }
   ```
3. Provide the Main Class:

   ```
   fatJar {
     classifier 'fat'
     manifest {
       attributes 'Main-Class': 'my.project.core.MyMainClass'
     }
     exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF'
   }
   ```
4. Create the fatjar:

   ```
   ./gradlew clean fatjar
   ```
5. Run the fatjar from /build/libs/ :

   ```
   java -jar MyFatJar.jar
   ```

Comment: From 2019: This suggestion does not work here. No dependencies are included in the fatjar

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I tried with Gradle 6.7

Runnable fat Jar (with all dependent libraries copied to the jar)

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
   
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.gradle.App'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } with jar
    
}
```

Runnable jar with all dependencies copied to a directory and adding the classpath to the manifest

```
    def dependsDir = "${buildDir}/libs/dependencies/"
    task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into "${dependsDir}"
    }
    task createJar(dependsOn: copyDependencies, type: Jar) {
      
        manifest {
            attributes('Main-Class': 'com.example.gradle.App',
                    'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { 'dependencies/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')
            )
        }
        with jar
    }
```

How to use  ?

- Add the above tasks to build.gradle
- Execute `gradle fatJar` //create fatJar
- Execute `gradle createJar` // create jar with dependencies copied.

More details : https://jafarmlp.medium.com/a-simple-java-project-with-gradle-2c323ae0e43d

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure Main Class to your Manifest

If you are using gradle project, just add the following into your build.gradle

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
               'Main-Class': 'pokerhandscorer.PokerHandScorer'
        )
    }
}
```

- Where 'pokerhandscorer' is the name of the package name,
  and PokerHandScorer is the main class name

This creates a jar file into your \build\libs{jarFilename}.jar

2. Run jar file using java -jar /{path}/{jarFileName.jar}

> java -jar /{path}/{jarFileName.jar}