# How to import&edit Jmeter jar file/jar plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, decompiler

I'm trying to import jar file **(** which is a plugin for jmeter-i would like to edit it and again i want to jar it in eclipse **)** in eclipse to see the source code of it.But im not able to see the source code of the jar file.

Can anyone help me how can i decompile a jar and make it editable in eclipse.

i decompiled online and used it in eclipse but eclipse is throwing number of errors.

By using **jd decompiler** i can view the .class of it .but i would like to edit the jar file according to my requirements.

Comment: If it's an open source project, then it has source code available online, together with instructions on how to compile it. If source code is not available online, then technically you are asking for help stealing the code...

Comment: @KirilS. the plugin which im trying to edit and make it executable jar is taken from [link](https://grafana.com/dashboards/1152) and i think its an open source.

Comment: @KirilS. When i open the jar file in jar decompiler [link](http://jd.benow.ca/) i can see the .class files ,but my requirement is to edit the files and compile back into executable jar.

Comment: why not download the code then from here, change and build it properly: https://github.com/NovaTecConsulting/JMeter-InfluxDB-Writer/releases? Why do you need to decompile it?

Comment: @KirilS.can you please tell how can i edit and build properly.Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

From comments you need Jmeter InfluxDB Plugin.

Download [source code](https://github.com/NovaTecConsulting/JMeter-InfluxDB-Writer/archive/v-1.0.zip) and uzip it.

Apply your fixes and use gradle to [build the jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721119/creating-runnable-jar-with-gradle) in Eclipse.