# How to set up a vanilla groovy project with main class executable via jar?

Tags: java, groovy, jar

I am getting very frustrated. I can't find a single, cohesive answer for my problem anywhere on the internet. Lots of documentation, nothing that brings it all together, though (that I can find).

All I need is someone to tell me:

- how to set up a groovy project (EDIT: Including where to put source files, in what directories, directory structure, etc.)
- assuming I haven't build groovy before
- or java before (I have, but work with me)
- in a way that I can specify a dependency (this is my dependency --> https://github.com/bpsm/edn-java) so probably using maven or gradle
- one that has a main class and a main method (again, work with me)
- at the end of the build, I need a jar file that I can execute via `java -jar <groovy-project>.jar` which prints out "hello world"

As simply as possible.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? If you know how to setup java project & and it is no different for groovy. Just need to add `groovy-all-xxx.jar` in the classpath.

Comment: @Rao I stated clearly in the question that I'm looking for an answer as if I didn't know how to set up a java project. Truthfully, I kind of don't. I've worked on java projects before and it's been a while since I've set one up, but I'm rusty

Comment: To create skeleton for the Groovy application (everything except external dependencies) run `gradle init --type groovy-application --dsl kotlin`. Right after it's done `gradle build` will give you JAR file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I strongly recommend Gradle; it is very simple to setup (though I too struggled when learning it). I added the resulting project in my [github](https://github.com/will-lp/gr8ex).

Let's create a project structure from zero without an IDE. I presume you already have [`$JAVA_HOME` set up](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Java-Home).

### 1. Creating the project structure

1. [Download Gradle](https://gradle.org/install) and put it in your `$PATH`
2. Create your directory project (I created `/tmp/gr8ex`)
3. Switch to it and run `gradle init` [1]
4. Edit the `build.gradle` created file and add these line:

   ```groovy
   plugins { // [2]
       id 'groovy'
   }

   repositories { mavenCentral() } // [3]

   dependencies { // [4]
       testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.8'
       compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.8'
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   }
   ```

Now the source files; we need to create the default directory structure that gradle uses (we can change it, but let's go with the defaults):

5. This is to create the source code dir:

   ```bash
   mkdir -p src/main/groovy
   ```
6. And the test source folder:

   ```bash
   mkdir -p src/test/groovy
   ```
7. The end result should look like this:

   ```bash
   gr8ex
       ├── build.gradle
       ├── gradle
       │   └── wrapper
       │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
       │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
       ├── gradlew
       ├── gradlew.bat
       ├── settings.gradle
       └── src
           ├── main
           │   └── groovy
           └── test
               └── groovy
   ```

### 2. Adding source code

1. Let's add a test package:

   ```
   mkdir -p src/test/groovy/org/gr8ex
   ```
2. And a test. I'm using `gedit src/test/groovy/org/gr8ex/HelloTest.groovy`:

   ```
   package org.gr8ex

   class HelloTest extends GroovyTestCase {
       void 'test Hello should return "Hello, World!"' () {
           assert new Hello().world == "Hello, World!"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Let's execute the test and check it fails:

   ```sh
   gradle test
   ```
4. Yep, it failed:

   ```sh
   /tmp/gr8ex/src/test/groovy/org/gr8ex/HelloTest.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class Hello 
    @ line 5, column 12.
             assert new Hello().world == "Hello, World!"
             ^

   1 error

   :compileTestGroovy FAILED
   ```
5. Let's add source folder

   ```sh
   mkdir -p src/main/groovy/org/gr8ex
   ```
6. And a source file (I used `gedit src/main/groovy/org/gr8ex/Hello.groovy`). Note it already have our `static main` method:

   ```
   package org.gr8ex

   class Hello {
       def getWorld() {
           "Hello, World!"
       }

       static main(args) {
           println new Hello().world
       }
   }
   ```
7. Test again (with `gradle test`) and assert we get the message `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`:

   ```sh
   $ gradle test
   :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
   :compileGroovy
   :processResources UP-TO-DATE
   :classes
   :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
   :compileTestGroovy
   :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
   :testClasses
   :test

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL

   Total time: 5.52 secs
   ```

Done. Time to create our application jar.

### 3. Creating the `jar` executable

There is a couple of ways to achieve that (like the [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)). I'm going to stick with a ["fatjar"](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/) approach.

1. Let's add a `fatjar` instruction in our `build.gradle` [5]:

   ```
   task fatjar(type: Jar) {
       manifest {
           attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.gr8ex.Hello'
       }
       from { 
           configurations
               .runtime
               .collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
       }
       with jar
   }
   ```
2. Packaging it:

   ```sh
   gradle fatjar
   ```
3. The resulting `jar` will be in `builds/libs/gr8ex.jar`. Let's execute it:

   ```sh
   $ java -jar build/libs/gr8ex.jar 
   Hello, World!
   ```
4. Profit! You can import this project with intellij and (I believe) eclipse.

---

[1]: Gradle creates some basic structure and add wrapper scripts so it can be executed without Gradle, if needed.

[2]: Here we are telling gradle that this project will use groovy

[3]: We tell gradle to use the `mavencentral` repository. JCenter is also very popular.

[4]: Here we are telling gradle that this project needs to use the groovy-all lib upon compilation and and testing phases

[5]: If you just stick with a `jar {}` instruction, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21721305/563890), you will end with a very thin jar which will be missing the groovy libs. This "fatjar" packs your libs into the jar. You might want to tweak it a bit depending on your use case.

Comment: also note, that there are plugins for creating a uber/fatjar for gradle.

Comment: @cfrick True! Added the shadow plugin reference.

Comment: glorious, thanks! +1 for giving me something without the need for an IDE.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! :-)

Comment: Thanks for this - it's a huge help for a newcomer like me. But as someone coming from a background of coding in languages other than Java/Groovy, how critical is the highly nested `src/{main,test}/groovy/org/gr8ex` directory structure? Is it possible to follow a flatter structure, for example with just a `src` directory containing a series of `xxx.groovy` files, and a `test` directory with the tests in it?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse may work pretty good with a Groovy Maven setup.  You just need a pom.xml similar to this:

```
...
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
          <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1-01</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7-01</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
            <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1-01</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>wherever/you/like</source>          
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
...
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>${groovyVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...
```

The sources part is optional, as it should look for your sources in src/main/groovy and src/test/groovy.  Eclipse should be able to configure your project as a maven project, and acquire automatically the Groovy nature as well.

A call to `mvn install` should generate a .jar file with your Groovy classes translated into .class files since you have configured a Groovy compiler in maven.

As for the main method, just do as you would normally with maven:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>my.mainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```