# Gradle for Java: Why do you have to specify source folder file path when specifying jar attributes

Tags: java, gradle

I just started trying out gradle for java. The documentation for the java plugin says that the default source folder is src/main/java, which to my understanding should be in the following structure:

```
|-build.gradle
|-src
   |-main
      |-java
```

[This is my groovy code for the build.gradle file.](https://pastebin.com/MBg4L3xC)

[And this is a picture of my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehaHl.png)

Why is it that I have to specifically list out the full path including the `src/main/java` in my `jar.mainfile` attribute instead of just `Backend.Main`? Shouldn't gradle automatically assume the source folder portion of the file path?

Edit: as the code is right now, I can build my jar file properly, but when I go to run it, I hit a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: *"Why is it that I have to specifically list out the full path including the`src/main/java` in my `jar.mainfile` attribute instead of just `Backend.Main`?"*  - Really?  What says you have to do that?  Where does it say it?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721119, the `mainfile` attribute should be the fully qualified class name; e.g. `Backend.Main` in your case.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more clear. I hit an exception when I try to run my jar file, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: You may have jumped to the wrong conclusion.  What does the `Main Class` attribute in the JAR's manifest actually contain?  What was the complete stacktrace for the exception?

Comment: Ah I got it. My package statement for Main.java included `src/main/java`.

Comment: So ... are you saying that you had a compilation error?  (The `package` statement is in the Java source code, and `package src/main/java/Backend.Main;` is invalid Java.)  Or are you saying something else.  (When you ask a question here it is very important that you say clearly and accurately what you mean.  Programming is a **precise** art, and you need to be precise when describing your problem ...)

Comment: That's correct. My full package statement was `package src/main/java/Backend`. The issue was that the gradle build process succeeded, so I thought it was able to compile my code fine. When I went to run my jar file, my code would throw a class not found exception. In any case, the problem was my package statement listing the full file path, which I can see now would cause problems for the builder.