# Create a Jar file with dependencies from settings.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build

I want to create a jar file which can be used by command like `java -cp .\TrendAnalyzer.jar trend_detect.Main`.
However, I can't find a way to create a jar file from settings.gradle, not build.gradle.
How can I create a jar file with dependencies from settings.gradle, which contains `include` etc. information.

Comment: Look into here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721119/creating-runnable-jar-with-gradle

Comment: Why just settings.gradle rather than build.gradle?

Comment: @Babl https://stackoverflow.com/a/21721305/3809427 is written in 2014 and it doesn't work. Shadow plugin works but https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/main/jaso92559 (in Japanese) is more appropriate than official document.

Comment: @utrucceh I don't know when it started, now Gradle generates settings.gradle and dependency information is written in settings.gradle . So I think it's needed to generate jar file. However, a Jar file can be generated by editting build.gradle according to https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/main/jaso92559 (in Japanese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add com.github.johnrengelman.shadow plugin to main module build.jar

```
plugins {
    // *snip*
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'jaso92559.app.App'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        // Define the main class for the application.
        attributes "Main-Class": "jaso92559.app.App"
    }
}
```

run `./gradle shadowJar` command on the path where settings.gradle exists.
In app\build\libs, app-all.jar file is generated and it can be run `java -jar app-all.jar`.

According to https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/main/jaso92559

Answer (score 0):

To create a jar file from settings.gradle, you can use the **jar** task in Gradle. This task allows you to package the compiled code and any dependencies into a jar file, which can then be executed using the **java** command with the **-cp** option.

Creating a jar file using the jar task in settings.gradle:

```
// settings.gradle
include ':trend_detect'

// build.gradle (in the trend_detect module)
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'trend_detect.Main'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { 

it.isDirectory() ? it : 
zipTree(it) }
        }
    }
```

The **include** statement in settings.gradle specifies that the trend_detect module should be included in the build.

In the **build.gradle** file for the **trend_detect** module, the jar task is defined to create a jar file with a **MANIFEST.MF** file that specifies the main class (trend_detect.Main). The **from** statement in the **jar** task specifies that the jar file should include all of the compiled code and dependencies from the **compile** configuration.

Once the jar file has been created, you can run it using the **java** command with the **-cp** option, as follows:

```
java -cp .\TrendAnalyzer.jar trend_detect.Main
```

This will execute the **main()** method in the **trend_detect.Main** class, using the compiled code and dependencies contained in the jar file.