# gradle 5 - windows java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, filename is too long

Tags: java, windows, gradle

Originally, [gradle windows java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, filename is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707110/gradle-windows-java-io-ioexception-createprocess-error-206-filename-is-too-lon) was a great solution. However, with gradle 5:

```
CollectionUtils.join(File.pathSeparator, classpath.getFiles())
```

fails with

```
 unknown property 'CollectionUtils' type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test
```

What would be a suitable fix for gradle 5.0?

At least for me:
https://github.com/viswaramamoorthy/gradle-util-plugins/ 
also fails with the same error on gradle 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it work after some tweaking

```
doFirst {
            if (org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
                def cp = org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.join(File.pathSeparator, classpath.getFiles())
                environment 'CLASSPATH', cp
                classpath = classpath.filter { false }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use external libraries in gradle buildscript.

example:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      // this dependency will be used in gradle build script.
      classpath 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
   }
}
//and use it like this in Your tasks
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(configurations.testRuntime,File.pathSeparator)
```

I am not sure if this will fix your issue though, but You can try other libraries like this also.

Comment: Intersting idea. However, this fails with: `> Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':module-name:compile' after it has been included in dependency resolution.`

Comment: It looks like its related to your project configuration ( or where You use it) You can try this approach on a simple project to see If it is suitable for you.

Comment: Indeed, it is a multi module project. Do you have an idea how to get it to work in a multi module setup?

Answer (score 1):

The following is for build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.ua.eshepelyuk:ManifestClasspath:1.0.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "ua.eshepelyuk.ManifestClasspath"`
```